# How to concatenate all CSVs in a directory, adding CSV name as a column with Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

- I have a folder with about 100 CSVs (`Downloads/challenges`).
- Each CSV has the same 50+ columns.
- Each CSV is titled something like `azerbaijan_challenge_entrants.csv`.

I want to create one new CSV (`all_entrants.csv`) that includes all data from all 100 CSVs, adding one new column: `challenge`, which should include the name of the CSV that the row data came from.

I generally like Python for tasks like this. But I am struggling to make this work. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I had to do this the other day and a simple search would have yielded this duplicate question - 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42757992/1313067

Comment: I looked at a couple [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2909975/896802) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2512386/896802) prior to writing this one, but did not find my answer or the specific question you refer to @Hatt.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is possible with `os` from the standard library and 3rd party library `pandas`:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

mypath = os.path.join('Downloads', 'challenges')

# get list of files
files = [f for f in os.listdir(mypath) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(mypath, f))]

# build list of dataframes, adding "challenge" column
dfs = [pd.read_csv(os.path.join(mypath, f)).assign(challenge=f) for f in files]

# concatenate dataframes into one
df = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)

# write to csv
df.to_csv('all_entrants.csv')
```